# React/Typescript, Styled Components, issues on injecting class definition

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a React app where a Styled Components have some styles. My goal is to dynamically add a CSS class definition (such as .color-red{color:red}) to this style. I don't want to dynamically change a CSS property but append a whole CSS to the existing one.

My Styled Component is

```
const LayoutWithGlobalStyle = styled.div<GlobalStyledType>`
  ${props => (
      `.test{background-color:red}
      color: lightgray;
      ${props.add}
      `
  )}
`
```

and it's used this way

```
<LayoutWithGlobalStyle add={globalStyle} id="layout-content-container" >
```

The GlobalStyledType is

```
type GlobalStyledType = {
    add: any;
};
```

At the beginning everything is working fine and the class eiEXnh is assigned to the LayoutWithGlobalStyle but when the variable globalStyle changes (it is passed through Redux) a new classname is assigned to the LayoutWithGlobalStyle, the new value is not added to the new class, all the previous CSS (`.test{background-color:red} and color:lightgray;`) is cleared and not present in the new class.

Any idea?

Comment: is it might be that you`r not rerendering your component

Comment: No, it rerenders properly